# React native compare keys with user key in all objects

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Ii is possible to compare keys with selectd key for example I have categories all, offer and payment according to user select I show this related data
I try to make above array but i don't know how to compare multiple keys with selected key in react native pls help thanks in advance. I used flatlist show data category wise...

```
notificationList: [
 {
 id: 0,
 title: 'Exclusive Brand Day Sale!! HURRY, LIMITED period offer!',
 date: '10 July, 2021',
 },
 {
 id: 1,
 title:
 'Order Placed successfully. It will be delivered on Mon 15 July, 2021',
 date: '5 July, 2021',
 },
 {
 id: 0,
 title: 'We have got coupons. collect now and save extras !!!',
 date: '5 June, 2021',
 },
 {
 id: 0,
 title:
 'Payment Failed. You can retry making a payment on order sections.',
 date: '20 April, 2021',
 },
 {
 id: [0, 2],
 title: 'Exclusive Brand Day Sale!! HURRY, LIMITED period offer!',
 date: '10 July, 2021',
 },
 {
 id: [0, 1],
 title:
 'Your order is delivered on time. for any further assistance please contact us. ',
 date: '5 July, 2021',
 },
 {
 id: 0,
 title: 'We have got coupons. collect now and save extras !!!',
 date: '5 June, 2021',
 },
 {
 id: 0,
 title:
 'Payment Failed. You can retry making a payment on order sections.',
 date: '20 April, 2021',
 },
 ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay the question isn't 100% clear but if I interpreted correctly, you want to only show the notifications of a selected key. For instance, if a user wanted all: show all, if they want offers: show only offers.

If not, the rest of this response is moot haha.

There are a few ways you could handle this. Most involve a useEffect function and useState variables. What will make this most tricky is that your ID variable isn't consistent. You have an array for some and a number for others. I would change it to be an array on every object instead of number since some will have more than one key listed. This is the best option in my option.

```
const [list, setList] = useState(notificationList)
const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(null)

useEffect(()=>{
   if (selectedId === null) {
     setList(defaultList) /// if not filter/id is set, show all.
 } else {
   /// if selectedId is set, filter out items that don't match.
   /// selectedId === [0,1]
    setList(() => {
    const newList = notificationList.filter(item => item.id.includes(id)) 
    return newList /// based on your data would return 1 item.
  })
 }
},[selectedId, list])
```

if changing your values to array on every object isn't really possible, you can restructure just your data on the client.

Option 1: in your useEffect, instead of

```
const newList = defaultList.filter(item => item.id.includes(id))
```

Do this

```
const newList = defaultList.filter(item => item.id.toString().includes(id))
```

Option 2: Restructure your notification list completely

```
const newList = notificationList.map((noti)=>{
return {...noti, id: noti.id.toString()}
})

const [list, setList] = useState(newList) << set the new list here instead of the default list.
const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(null) // will now be an Array when set ex: [0] or [0,1]

// in your useEffect, use restructured data instead of default notification list data.
```

Hope this helps!